# Call JavaScript function specified in a child <frame>

Tags: c#, javascript, html, dom

Here's the common HTML structure of parent page (`index.html`):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test title</title>
</head>
    <frameset cols="150,*">
        <frame name="left" src="testleft.html">
        </frame>
        <frame name="right" src="testright.html">
        </frame>
  </frameset>
 </html>
```

Here's the common HTML structure of child page (`testleft.html`):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function proc1(frm) {
                alert("called proc1");
                frm.setAttribute("id", "change!!");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>This is testpage.</p>
        <form name="TestFormName" action="get" id="TestFormId">
            <input type="text" value="TextValueEmpty" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to call `proc1()` on testleft.html using C#. I tried to use `WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript()`, but it can't call `proc1()`. How do I do that?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript()` can only be used to call JScript functions, but since your function is deeper we have to create a small "function" to access your function. The WebBrowser control doesn't have any way of doing that, so we have to use a "hack":

We will navigate to `javascript:code` in order to execute our code. In order to reach our function proc1, we have to use this small snippet: `top.frames[0].proc1()`.

So, to put it all together, we have to write one simple line of C# code:

```
WebBrowser.Navigate("Javascript:top.frames[0].proc1()");
```